Is it grammatically correct to say "at speed" or "at altitude"?
I often see people writing things such as "we took off at speed" to indicate a fast rate of travel, or "I trained at altitude" to indicate a high elevation. Is this grammatically correct?
It seems to me like it's an improper sentence because there is no specification exactly what the speed was or what the elevation was. Couldn't it be any speed or any elevation? We all understand that these mean fast and high, but is it grammatically correct to leave out the what?

Do dictionaries license the phrase 'at speed'? It's a fixed phrase, arguably extragrammatical, which would make it an extragrammatical idiom. // You'll find 'at altitude' defined and hence licensed in Merriam-Webster; they agree that it's an idiom (and as it's transparent, the words not having unusual meanings, it must be an extra-grammatical idiom).

@EdwinAshworth What makes these somehow an “idiom” or “extra-grammatical”, and how are they fundamentally different from any number of commonplace expressions such as at anchor, at arm’s length, at bat, at cost, at court, at dinner, at ease, at fault, at grade, at gunpoint, at hand, at heart, at home, at infinity, at issue, at length, at liberty, at night, at par, at play, at present, at random, at rest, at sea, at stake, at unison, at war, at will? I see a pattern, not an exception. You?

@tct The expressions you list certainly differ from the prototypical and I'd say the vast majority of other at-phrases (locatives at the school, at the bus stop, at the pub, at the hospital, at the swimming pool, at the beach, at the door, at the bottom, at his desk ... ... // temporals at the moment, at this time, at the start, at any moment ... //  transparent-metaphorical at the races, at the opera, at the circus, at the crack of dawn, at the bottle, at her best ... // more-opaque-metaphorical _at his old tricks, at her leisure). I'd say the norm includes a determiner.

At speed is attested in the OED since the 18th century. Speed in English has long referred to swiftness or high speed. (Originally it referred to abundance or success; compare Old High German spuon "to prosper, succeed".) So using it to mean swiftness is perfectly fine.
The first OED citation for "at speed" is:

"Always at speed, and never drawing bit." William Cowper, 1781 ("draw bit" means "to stop or slow one's horse by pulling at the reins", OED).


"We were galloping at speed when an unfortunate marais received my horse." (Sir Robert T. Wilson, Private diary of travels, personal services, and public events 1812–14, 1849)

Before this, there were similar forms including "in speed", "on speed", "upon speed" ("in speed" is Middle English, "on speed" 17th century). In Old English, it was commonly used in the dative plural to mean swiftly, so the prepositions can be seen as replacing the dative when the dative disappeared from the English language.
And there are adjectives and adverbs like "speedy", "speedily" which mean at high speed, so the sense of "speed" as meaning "celerity, swiftness" is widespread. It goes back to Old and Middle English, for instance "wið sped" ("with speed", i.e. quickly, in a c. 1250 translation of the Bible).
"At altitude" is more recent, but "altitude" as referring to an extremely high state goes back to Early Modern English (OED): "High degree or eminence of any quality or attribute; high rank or position on a scale of power, attainment, etc.; an instance of this."
